# Removing tcast for tuples

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'm in a bind with a goal equality like this (the details don't matter, I think):

```
tcast tc0
[tuple of take i (s_bs bs) ++ drop i.+1 (s_bs bs) ++ [:: [ffun⇒ 0]]] 
=
...
```

How do I get rid of the `tcast` and `tuple` to go back to simple `seq` (I tried the `val_inj` trick, but this didn't seem to remove the type cast)?

Thanks in advance.

Bye,

Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a precise answer is a bit difficult, since you did not provide any reproducible testcase. But you could try rewriting your goal using the following lemma, once you have applied `val_inj`.

```
Lemma val_tcast {T} m n (tc : n = m) (x : n.-tuple T) :
  val (tcast tc x) = val x.
Proof. now case tc. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; this is exactly what I was searching for, and my tentatives were much more complicated than your solution. But I'm unfamiliar with the `now` construct (I don't see it in the Ssreflect Inria report from 2009), and it's unclear to me how `case` differs from Ssreflect `case:`. The same report indeed mentions a diffferent treatment on equalities than Coq `case`, but a bit of explanation would be very helpful. Again, thanks.

Comment: I see that `now` is not specific to Ssreflect, but involves Coq `easy` tactic. In fact, a more SSreflect-typical `by` works too in lieu of `now`. Thanks again.

Comment: That is right; you cannot use the `case:` tactic from SSReflect; you need to use instead the vanilla `case` tactic. That is why I used `now` rather than `by`, so as to make it clear I was using vanilla tactics rather than SSReflect ones. Using only SSReflect tactics, I do not know how to make it shorter than `exact: (match tc with Logic.eq_refl => _ end)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this Ssreflect-compliant way to handle that case. It's not that much longer... and as apparently magical :)

Comment: The form for ssreflect is `Proof. by case: m / tc. Qed.` as you need to hint the index to avoid the extra generalization. Indeed `case: idx / term` is very useful but hard to see in the tutorials / doc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that, at least in the cases I had to handle, a proper use of rewrites using `tcastE` and `tnth_nth` (which forced a cast to `nat`), followed by a partial evaluation via `/=`, gets rid of the `tcast`.