# Removing tcast from tuples... Season 2

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I'd like to remove `tcast` in a "lemma" such as the following one. But this doesn't even typecheck, due to dependent-typing "constraints".

```
Lemma foo : forall {T} m n (tc : n = m) (f : m.-tuple T -> 'I_n -> nat) (x : n.-tuple T),
    [seq f (tcast tc x) j | j <- enum 'I_n] =  
    [seq f x j | j <- enum 'I_n].
```

In fact, a more significant example for the application I have in mind, and which does typecheck, would be the following lemma:

```
Lemma bar n1 n2 n (tc : n1 + n2 = n) (l1 : n1.-tuple nat) (l2 : n2.-tuple nat) :
  \sum_(i < n) tnth (tcast tc [tuple of (l1 ++ l2)]) i = 
  \sum_(i < n1) tnth l1 i + \sum_(i < n2) tnth l2 i.
```

This would be simple on `seq`, but here I cannot find how to proceed using lemmas in tuple.v or fintype.v.

So what is the proper way to address such `tcast` expressions when they don't seem to be amenable to treatment via `val_inj` and case analysis (see previous post)? Do I have, in the first example, to introduce two versions of `f`, later proved to be equal over sequences (and if so, what would be the best way to proceed)?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Pierre

Comment: I'm afraid we need a bit more context Pierre, indeed the above expression cannot type as your types are biased towards `'I_n`

Comment: I'd guess the way I'd proceed here is to lift the cast upwards, if `f` is really making use of the size information.

Comment: Thanks, Emilio, for the answer. The point is that the `tcast` is in fact useless here, since we can assume `n = m`. If we were dealing with lists instead of tuples, this would be a no-op. So is there an easy way to force the whole reasoning here on `seq`, the subtype of tuples? I also looked at `tcastE`, but this lost me...

Comment: I suggest you post you current context, like this it is indeed hard to see what the problem. is. Maybe you'd like to have a cast for `f`, such as `Definition fcast {T} m n (tc : n = m) (f : n.-tuple T -> 'I_n -> nat) :
  m.-tuple T -> 'I_m -> nat.
Proof. by case: m / tc; exact: f. Defined.
` or written explicitly: `
Definition fcast' {T} m n (tc : n = m) (f : n.-tuple T -> 'I_n -> nat) :
  m.-tuple T -> 'I_m -> nat :=
  match tc with
  | erefl => f
  end.`

Comment: I provide elements to answer this question [in a related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61758748/13416365).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you post, you can remove the casts using the standard trick:

```
Lemma val_tcast {T} m n (tc : n = m) (x : n.-tuple T) :
  val (tcast tc x) = val x.
Proof. by case: m / tc. Qed.

Lemma sum_tuple n (t : n.-tuple nat) :
 \sum_(i < n) tnth t i = \sum_(i < n) nth 0 (val t) i.
Proof. by apply: eq_bigr => ? ?; rewrite (tnth_nth 0). Qed.

Lemma bar n1 n2 n (tc : n1 + n2 = n) (l1 : n1.-tuple nat) (l2 : n2.-tuple nat) :
  \sum_(i < n) tnth (tcast tc [tuple of (l1 ++ l2)]) i =
  \sum_(i < n1) tnth l1 i + \sum_(i < n2) tnth l2 i.
Proof.
rewrite !sum_tuple val_tcast /=.
```

Tho there is a direct proof:

```
Lemma bar' n1 n2 n (tc : n1 + n2 = n) (l1 : n1.-tuple nat) (l2 : n2.-tuple nat) :
  \sum_(i < n) tnth (tcast tc [tuple of (l1 ++ l2)]) i =
  \sum_(i < n1) tnth l1 i + \sum_(i < n2) tnth l2 i.
Proof. by rewrite -!(big_tuple _ _ _ predT id) val_tcast big_cat. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Emilio. I see you use the `tnth_nth` approach I mentioned before, and you can avoid an explicit use of `tcastE`;  this is elegant :)